# Perl While loop Http and HTTPS responses

Tags: perl

```
$resp = $ab->request(HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url));
$rrs = $resp->content;



while(($rrs =~ m/<a href=\"https?:\/\/(.*?)\//g)  &&  ($rrs =~ m/<a href=\"?http:\/\/(.*?)\//g)){
```

Comment: any suggessions ?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: The comment by @choroba isn't just so: I can't even guess what you want?  I suggest you edit the question and nicely state what"s going on. (Btw, those two regex should be one, as it seems. But that's not the question, is it.)

Comment: Maybe we should have a [Name that Tune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_That_Tune) competition where we see who can get the right answer with the fewest parts of the question. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your example cuts off, but it looks like you want to fetch a resource, extract links, and maybe do other things. I suggest that you let [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org) do that for you. It can fetch the resource, parse the HTML (`dom`), extract other links (in `map`), and select the ones with the right scheme (first `grep`):

```
use v5.10;

use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

my @queue = ( $ARGV[0] );

my %Seen; # don't process things we've already seen
while( my $this = shift @queue ) {
    say "Processing $this";

    my $tx = $ua->get( $this );

    my @links = $tx->result
        ->dom
        ->find( 'a' )
        ->map( attr => 'href' )
        ->grep( sub { Mojo::URL->new($_)->scheme =~ /https?/ } )
        ->grep( sub { ! $Seen{$_} } )
        ->each;

    say "\t", join "\n\t", @links;

    push @queue, @links;
    }
```

I write about all of this with lots of examples in [Mojolicious Web Clients](https://leanpub.com/mojo_web_clients).

Comment: thanks for reply basically what i wana do is using while loop reading responses as href value starting with https and http i want both of those and my script not supporting | or && even with or without use strict or warnings

Comment: @ivan Add any clarifications to your original question, which you can edit. Include what and why. I still don't understand what you are after.